# How can I add a callback or hook to a Python builtin class method?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to gather information on files being opened and closed so I can keep track of which processes is doing what. I work with users that will not systematically use custom I/O functions and methods so I would like to change the behavior of builtins.

I figured out a way to change the open function. It might not be optimal, but it works.

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import io
import logging
import __builtin__


def custom_open(file_name, access_mode, buffering = 0):
    logging.debug('Opening file ' + file_name)    
    return __builtin__.open(file_name, access_mode, buffering)

logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

open = custom_open

f = open('workfile', 'w')

f.write('This is a test\n')       

f.close()
```

What I would now like to do is change the behavior of the file close method. I tried a few things but nothing works.

Comment: Unlike some other languages, Python doesn't allow monkey-patching of builtins. So you won't be able to override `file`'s methods with your own. What you *can* do is subclass `file`, define your own `close` method to wrap `file`'s, and then make it so that your `custom_open` returns that subclassed `file` class rather than the default.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this makes sense. That's one route I had considered. If the custom_file inherits from the builtin file, I should be able to selectively override the builtin methods that I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little on my comment, since nobody else seems to be submitting an answer:

```
# Create a custom file class
class custom_file(file): 
    def close(self): 
        # do logging
        super(file, self).close()

# create a custom file opener
def custom_open(*args, **kwargs):
    # do logging
    return custom_file(*args, **kwargs)

# Set local `open` to point to your custom_open fn
open = custom_open
```

Implicit here (and I didn't do research so it could be wrong) is that `open('bla')` is just calling out to `file.__init__('bla')`, so be careful there.

edit: You might also want to make sure you're overriding other methods on `file`, like `flush` or anything else that would cause Python to touch your disk.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot. One minor typo is that `super(file, self).close()` should be `super(custom_file, self).close()`.